# What is the meaning of "as" in the following sentences?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "as" in the following sentences,

> 1) "It's incredible," Andy quoted Jennifer **as** saying.
>
> 2) "The food was delicious," Jack was quoted **as** saying by the
>   newspaper.

Does "Andy quoted Jennifer as saying" mean "Andy quoted Jennifer as Andy was saying" ? or "Andy quoted that Jennifer said" ?

Does "Jack was quoted as saying by the newspaper" mean "Jack was quoted by newspaper that Jack said" or "Jack was quoted by newspaper as newspaper was saying" ?

What is the difference in meaning between " Andy quoted Jennifer **as** saying" and "Andy quoted Jennifer saying" ?

What is the difference in meaning between "Jack was quoted **as** saying by the newspaper" and "Jack was quoted saying by the newspaper" ?

Comment: Andy quoted the words that Jennifer had said. Leaving out the _as_ doesn't change the meaning, it just makes it incorrect English.

Comment: If so, what does "as" mean in the sentences? What is "as" ? What is the difference in meaning between "Andy quoted Jennifer as saying" and "Andy quoted Jennifer"? What is "as saying" mean?

Comment: To paraphrase, Andy said it **just like** Jennifer said it.

Comment: it's not possible to say 'what it means', it's just the way the language works. A similar construction is "Mr X was reported as having done [this]", meaning "It was reported that Mr X had...".